# ArchUnit: Is there a way to visualize violations?

Tags: intellij-idea, archunit

With ArchUnit violations can be frozen so that things do not get worse. The problem that remains is that there is nothing which indicates the frozen violations in daily coding.

Is there a way to visualize the violations in the IDE? E.g. as inspection problem in IntelliJ.

If not, what is your approach to constantly reduce the frozen violations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of [Any plans for Intellij Plugin Development](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/942) to show violations as inspections.

The discussions about [ArchUnit Trends](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/597) and [Freezing rule violations as SonarQube metric](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/425) might be more realistic:

- Many projects just use a simple (possibly `wc -l`-based) count of stored violations as a metric.
- [Stefan Röck](https://github.com/stefanroeck) has implemented [an   XmlFileBasedViolationStore](https://gist.github.com/stefanroeck/0e7b2002eb0e801b8ff619e6738048db) which is possibly useful to import violations in other tools.

Comment: Thank you for reflecting the current state of thoughts on this topic. I will pursue the topic based on the linked tickets.